# What is the most simple (and correct) escaping algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, escaping

Disclaimer: this is theoretical question with the purpose of increasing my understanding. I know that I can always use tools like a JSON library to solve the problem.

Suppose I want to create a comma separated list of values which may themselves contain comma's. These commas need to be escaped first. Assuming that I use `.` as the escape character then `["a", "b,c"]` becomes `a,b.,c`.

However, if one of the values originally contained a `.,` sequence then we'd need to escape those *before* escaping the commas. So `[ "a", "b.,c" ]` becomes `a,b..,c`.

However, if one of the values originally contained a `..,` sequence then we'd need to escape those *before* escaping the commas. So `[ "a", "b..,c" ]` becomes `a,b...,c`.

However, if one of the values originally contained a `...,` sequence then we'd need to escape those *before* escaping the commas. So `[ "a", "b...,c" ]` becomes `a,b....,c`.

Etc...

The decoding process must perform the reversed recursion.

However, I suspect if I'm making it too hard and there is a simpler way. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why you feel that is too complex ? Find an escape character, check what follows it, do an action based on that, repeat.

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler?"  This seems inherently subjective.

Comment: First, expecting people to leave this site to go figure out what you're asking isn't usually how SO works (your question becomes meaningless if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason). Second, since you have working code and you're looking to improve it, this really belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Why would you escape "..," to "...,"? I think the typical approach would be to separately escape each literal "." to "..", and each "," to ".,".  So "..," would become ".....,".

Comment: @mbeckish Doh! That might be it.

Comment: @mbeckish seconded :) i think you should write that as an answer, as it is _the_ common answer for this problem and other people might be looking for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @mkbeckish' comment I realized that the algorithm can be implemented as:

```
// encoding
text.replace(escape, escape + escape);
text.replace(delim , escape + delim);

// decoding
text.replace(escape + delim , delim);
text.replace(escape + escape, escape);
```

[Example implementation.](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=918b9a31ca244fccc1bc19f92f7911bd)

It's silly that I didn't realize this myself..

Comment: I don't think this covers the storage of multiple values as shown in your question. For example, you can encode `[ "a", "b," ]` into `"a,b.,"`, but if you just do a simple string split on `,` followed by your decoding algorithm, you'll get `[ "a", "b.", "" ]`. If you do the decoding first and then the string split, you'll get `[ "a", "b", "" ]`.

Comment: Sorry; I think I used the wrong word. I was referring to the process of encoding each string in the array and then joining the result using a comma as shown in the  first example in your question.

Comment: Prove me wrong with an actual example and I'll fix it. If you want you can use [this file](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66a1eec3ab32b592) as a starting point.

Comment: I already gave you some example data, but you haven't provided an implementation to run it. Your implementation does the encoding but not the aggregation of multiple strings into a single string.

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you are saying. Sorry.